# Can't use merged types in React props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I create the following 2 types in theme.interface.ts:

```
type ThemeSizing =
  | 'px'
  | '1'
  | '1/2'
  | 'full'
  | 'fit'

type ThemeWidthSpecific = 'svw' | 'lvw' | 'dvw'
type ThemeHeightSpecific = 'svh' | 'lvh' | 'dvh'
```

I create the merged types:

```
export type ThemeWidth = ThemeSizing & ThemeWidthSpecific
export type ThemeHeight = ThemeSizing & ThemeHeightSpecific
```

I declare the interface for the component in list.component.tsx:

```
interface ListProps {
  items: ReactNode[]
  width?: ThemeWidth
}
```

###### Error code in list.component.tsx:

TS2322: Type string is not assignable to type never

###### Error code in page.tsx (imported list component here):

TS2322: Type string is not assignable to type undefined
list.component.tsx(22, 3): The expected type comes from property width which is declared here on type IntrinsicAttributes & ListProps

Perhaps I have to make the 2 created types optional. Couldn't find any solutions on the web unfortunately.

Comment: What possible string values do you think are **both** `ThemeSizing` **and** `ThemeWidthSpecific`? Presumably you wanted another union, not an intersection.

Comment: There are no shared string values. I wanted to have 2 types and 1 shared type (height, width + shared string values). Would that be an union?

Comment: Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).

Comment: You have a typo. `ThemeSizing & ThemeWidthSpecific` should be `ThemeSizing | ThemeWidthSpecific`. Everything is happening properly here - `never` is correct. All you need to do is hover over `ThemeWidth` to see that it's correctly `never`.

Comment: @AndyRay Thanks a lot! Now the error is gone but I have to figure out why the css is not  working accordingly. Feel free to answer so I can mark it as the solution! :-)

Comment: @KaioDev I don't think this question/answer will be valuable to anyone else, so I voted to close, as Stackoverflow has a specific closing option for questions caused by typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood union and intersection types.

Imagine the union to be an "or" statement. In you're case:

```
type ThemeSizing =
  | 'px'
  | '1'
  | '1/2'
  | 'full'
  | 'fit'
```

Means that ThemeSizing can be 'px' or '1' or '1/2' ....

The same also goes for type ThemeWidthSpecific = 'svw' | 'lvw' | 'dvw'

Now an intersection using `&` means that you're using an "and" so this code here:

```
export type ThemeWidth = ThemeSizing & ThemeWidthSpecific
```

means that ThemeWidth must be ThemeSizing and ThemeWidthSpecific. In this case, because there is no overlap between the two, this is never possible so Typescript shows the never error.

The easy fix: `type ThemeWidth = ThemeSizing | ThemeWidthSpecific`

A side note: if the two types ThemeSizing and ThemeWidthSpecific had a common string, then ThemeWidth could only equal that common string when using the intersection.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Also thanks for the side note. It will definitely avoid future errors.